# How to use Jersey's internal routing mechanism to extract a class/method reference?

Tags: java, routes, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Jersey 1.8 application running. Jersey is running as a Servlet.

I need to write a **servlet filter** that given a plain request/response, is able to figure out which REST resource/method will respond to the request and extract values from annotations.

For example, imagine I have the following resource:

```
@Path("/foo")
@MyAnnotation("hello")
public class FooResource {
   @GET
   @Path("/bar")
   @MyOtherAnnotation("world")
   public Response bar(){ 
      ... 
   }
}
```

When a request `GET /foo/bar` comes in, I need my servlet filter to be able to extract the values `"hello"` and `"world"` from `MyAnnotation` and `MyOtherAnnotation` before Jersey's own servlet processes the request.

This filter logic should be able to work for all requests and all resources registered.

Is there a way to access Jersey's internal routing mechanism to obtain a class/method reference where Jersey will dispatch the request?

I'm open to other suggestions as well, but ideally nothing like trying to hack my own routing mechanism by reading the `@Path` annotations myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
    @Context // request scoped proxy
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

   @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        if (resourceInfo.getResourceClass().isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotationion.class) ||
            resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().isAnnotationPresent(MyOtherAnnotation.class)) {
```

to register the filter use

```
bind(AuthFilter.class).to(ContainerRequestFilter.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a JAXRS filter. What i have to use is a servlet filter (implementing `doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)`) and from there, somehow obtain a reference to the resource class and method. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: you're almost going to implement another jersey in your filter :) may be just upgrade to Jersey2?

Comment: another way is to use class instrumentation. basically, attach an aspect to every resource method.

Comment: The issue is that this I'm working on a enterprise legacy framework that requires an identifier for the URI being requested to be provided (for monitoring reasons) BEFORE the request is handed over to the Jersey application. Changing/upgrading isn't an option here, so in order to avoid re-inventing the wheel, i wanted to see if Jersey could come to the rescue by using the routing component by itself and centralize URI-specific data in the resource. This seems not feasible, so i'll accept defeat and implement something else.