# Debug Jersey mapping/routing execution before reaching endpoints/resources

Tags: jersey, glassfish

I have been working with Glassfish/Jackson for over a year and I always have this problem when introducing a new endpoint implementation: when **the endpoint is not reached and I want to understand why**, the only hints I have to go on are the returned request, since the execution *doesn't reach the desired endpoint or resource* (routing/mapping error).

I want to **intercept the Jersey mapping/routing execution before reaching endpoints/resources**, with the "raw" request, so that I can better understand resource/endpoint mapping and routing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31828879/3399416) to a *different* question, by [@xeye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273542/xeye), solved this problem for me:

Create a filter that implements `ContainerRequestFilter`, and override its `filter` method. This will be where we can **intercept all requests** for debugging.

```
// Executed whenever a request is sent to the API server.
// Useful for debugging errors that don't reach the desired endpoint implementation.
@Provider
@Priority(value = 0)
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Context // request scoped proxy
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        try {
            // put a breakpoint or log desired attributes of requestContext here.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore
        }
   }
}
```

Then **register this new class** in your `ConfigResource` implementation.

```
public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyResourceConfig(){
        register(MyFilter.class);
        // ...
    }
```

([It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))